# Getting Bad file descriptor Error with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

My Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  printf("Process %d on %s out of %d\n", rank, processor_name, numprocs);

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

the command to run:

```
mpirun -np 2 -machinefile mach_list a.out
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
[noor-desktop:04209] [[50859,0],1]->[[50859,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler: writev failed: Bad file descriptor (9) [sd = 9]
[noor-desktop:04209] [[50859,0],1]->[[50859,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler: writev failed: Bad file descriptor (9) [sd = 9]
[noor-desktop:04209] [[50859,0],1] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[50859,0],0] lost
[noor-desktop:04209] [[50859,0],1] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[50859,0],0] lost
```

The content of the machine file is:
`noor@192.168.1.4`

`noor@192.168.1.4` is ok, I've logged in using ssh without password for I've already copied the public key there.

Comment: what is in your machine file?I think the problem is from your machine file.

Comment: see the edits,2 last line, thanks

Comment: noptes, now i'm getting the same problem again, 
mpiexec -n 2 -machinefile mach_list a.out 
[noor-desktop:02668] [[39477,0],1]->[[39477,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler: writev failed: Bad file descriptor (9) [sd = 9]
[noor-desktop:02668] [[39477,0],1] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[39477,0],0] lost
[noor-desktop:02668] [[39477,0],1]->[[39477,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler: writev failed: Bad file descriptor (9) [sd = 9]
[noor-desktop:02668] [[39477,0],1] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[39477,0],0] lost

Comment: No I mean your machine(such as a single computer or server,...)

Comment: hmmm, the machine is a server

Comment: Up to now I worked with a server computer that has two intel xeon cpu, in my case I don't use any machine file and run my codes with this script "mpiexec -n N /path to excitable file"and my operating system is ubuntu too if you have problem yet you can send your problem to mpi mail list         (mpich-discuss@mcs.anl.gov) they can help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9281/discussion-between-noor-and-ehsan)